# Selenium WebDriver: findElements only returns the first 2 instances of element

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to gather a list of `webelements` from an `AJAX` dropdown menu to iterate over for verifying the value of each item.

The way I've done that is by this code:

```
List<WebElement> names = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
names = pgNew.driver.findElements(By.className("col1"));
```

However, when I run this, `names` only takes in the first two items by the `className col1` and not all 15. Instead, it stores the last 13 spots as blank. For example, if it was supposed to take in:

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o

it only takes in:

a, b, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="iceSelInpTxt patientAutoComplete">
    <input id="mainForm:TextBox">
    <div id="mainForm:TextBox_div">
        <div>
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtSelRow AutoCompleteSelRow">
                <span class="informal">
                    <table class="table" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <td class="col1">Text</td>
                                <td class="col3">Text</td>
                                <td class="col1">Text</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </span>
                <span style="visibility:hidden;display:none;">MRN5218317218</span>
            </div>
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
            <div class="iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="mainForm:TextBox_idx" style="" value="">
</div>
```

the following "iceSelInpTxtRow pAutoCompleteSelRow" are all the same with different values for "col1", "col3" and "col1".

Also, a note, this issue is only happening in FireFox.

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML snippet, it may provide a little clue. Thanks.

Comment: A screen shot or something? I don't think I can show that because it is company software that I'm testing.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't need to see the whole html, just the snippet that is this dropdown menu. But if you can't provide that, it will make debugging this much trickier.

Comment: @SidQuraishi, it being 'company software' won't make a difference - anonymise the data, break it down to as simple as you can. You just need a concrete example that proves this problem, we don't want to see your company secrets, and we are not asking you to provide them either.

Comment: @SidQuraishi when you click on the dropdown are you able to see all the values physically on the screen or do you have to scroll to see them?

Comment: I hope this is good enough. This issue is only happening in FireFox :s

Comment: @SidQuraishi What version of firefox and webdriver are you using?

Comment: @AlexPeña
FireFox says it is up to date.
How do I check driver version?
Also, I can see all the values physically on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a total shot in the dark but I ran into what sounds like the exact problem you're having except I couldn't see my elements physically on the screen but when I pulled up the HTML all the elements were there. I found that it was a change in behavior with Firefox v16+, any version prior to that worked fine for me. I never did find out what that change was but in order to get around it I had to use a bit of JavaScript to 'scroll the element into view'. Hopefully this helps you or at least gets you going in the right direction. Take a look at my post:

[WebElement getText() is an empty string in Firefox if element is not physically visible on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398520/webelement-gettext-is-an-empty-string-in-firefox-if-element-is-not-physically)

Comment: By the way the webdriver version can be found on the name of the jar you're using, for instance you might have something like 'selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar'. Just make sure you're using the latest version if you're using the latest version of Firefox

Comment: Turns out the webdriver version meant a lot. Thanks for letting me know :D