# unable to get theaders

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

im currently having a problem in getting the headers title of a table to make a validation, it work great until column 6, because when it goes to next one which isn't visible the .getText() is blank. I no the xpath is correct.

```
public void getAndSaveDataOfTable (final String tabla) throws FileNotFoundException{    
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tabla)); 
    List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.xpath("th"));
    Assert.assertTrue(elements.size() > 1);
    int cantelements = elements.size();

    for (int i = 1; i <= cantelements; i++) {   
        String data = driver.findElement(
            By.xpath(".//div[@class='ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box']//table/thead/tr/th["+ i + "]/span[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println("EL nombre del encabezado " + i + " " + data);
        datosFila.put(i, data);
    }
```

So between column 7and 20 I can't get the text of the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into what sounds like what you're running into. Take a look at my post on

[WebElement getText() is an empty string in Firefox if element is not physically visible on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398520/webelement-gettext-is-an-empty-string-in-firefox-if-element-is-not-physically)

I ended up solving it by using a little bit of JavaScript to columns "into view". Hopefully this helps you out.

```
private void scrollToElement(WebElement element){
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}
```

Comment: So when i reach the column I can't see I call this function? Sorry for the question im new to to this.

Comment: Yes you would. in your loop for instance after you've found the element just pass it in to the function.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to be using the `JavascriptExecutor` several times (you said your issue is on multiple columns 7-20) I would suggest you can optimize by running JS only once and then iterating through in Java, rather than running JS again for every operation. The `JavascriptExecutor` is slow, and you'll save whole seconds on the total test time by avoiding even 12+ extra JS executions.

```
// JavaScript to get text from tHeads
String getTheadTexts =  
"var tHeads = []; " +
"for (i = o; i < 20; i++) { " +
    "var cssSelector = 'div.ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box table thead tr th' + i + ' span:nth-of-type(1)'; " +
    "var elem = document.querySelector(cssSelector); " +
    "var elemText = ''; " +
    "if ((elem.textContent) && (typeof (elem.textContent) != 'undefined')) { " +
        "tHeads.push(elem.textContent); " +
    "} else { " +
        "tHeads.push(elem.innerText); " +
    "} " +
"} " +
"return tHeads; ";

// Execute the JS to populate a List
List<String> tHeadTexts = (ArrayList<String>) js.executeScript(getTheadTexts);

// Do some operation on each List item
int i = 0;
for (String data: tHeadTexts){
    System.out.println("EL nombre del encabezado " + i + " " + data);
    datosFila.put(i, data);
    i++;
}
```