# webelement.text not work (browser = webdriver.Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to extract text between `<tag></tag>` (In my case, `<tr></tr>`). so, I'm using webelement.text

```
self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
table = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('table')
....
rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
print rows
for element in rows:
    print type(element)
    print element.text
    print type(element.text)
```

and output is:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0151E390>] # <-print rows
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'> # <-print type(element)
# <-nothing from print element.text
<type 'unicode'> # <-print type(e.text)
```

So there is nothing  from element.text, but the  tags is not empty. `<tr>blablabla</tr>`

I got no possibility to check it on other browsers.

The problem is with `<tr>`
It dont see text inside  `<tr>blabla</tr>`:

`rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')` will be emplty.

But it see it inside `<tr><td>blabla</td></tr>`:

```
rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for element in rows:
    print element.text # <-blabla
```

Though, it doesnt work on **any** nested element:

```
<tr><h1>blabla</h1></tr>:
```

`rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')` will be emplty.
The [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) on `webelement.text` says just

> text
>
> ```
> Gets the text of the element.
> ```
>
> Its just dont consider text inside `<tr>text</tr>` as the text of the `<tr>` element, I suppose.

Comment: Show us the HTML being tested against.

Comment: Everything is ok with HTML, it tracks the number of elements, it return correct element.tag_name          `<table>
    <tr>blablabla</tr>

</table>`

Comment: BTW its a Django project

Comment: have you tried to cast your `element.text` with `str()` ? (`str(element.text)`)

Comment: Tried. No use. Its empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only guessing, but is the text you're looking for actually in a child node (`<td>` maybe?)?

I'm not sure how pythons `webelement.text` works, but maybe you need to get the text of the child elements.

**EDIT:** I think your problem might actually be that having text between `<tr>` tags is invalid HTML, and is not being stored in the DOM as you might expect.

When I create a simple table with text in a row...

```
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Text in 1st cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text in 2nd cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      Text in 3rd Row
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

The resulting DOM actually looks like this...

```
<body>
  Text in 3rd Row
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Text in 1st cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Text in 2nd cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

So you can see there actually isn't any text in the third `<tr>`, which explains what you're seeing.

So please post your actual HTML/DOM, so that we can see if there actually is any text inside the tag you're expecting

Comment: Its not a child node.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may be hitting some kind of bug. Here is a related post where they describe that Firefox returns empty text if the element is not visible at the time of the webelement.text invocation. They also propose a solution by doing a scroll to the element using javascript.

Check if your Firefox version is affected and try to update or implement the workaround.

Please let us know how you progress!

Link: [WebElement getText() is an empty string in Firefox if element is not physically visible on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15436483/2307129)

Comment: In my case, it IS physically visible.

Comment: Can you share the web page you are using so I can test it on my computer? Also please share the version of selenium/python as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the tag name table

```
 rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('Table')
 print rows
 for element in rows:
     print type(element)
     print element.text
     print type(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I listed all elements for td and it finds 5 of them instead of 1. So I took text from the last one elem[-1].text and it workred for me

```
(Pdb) elem = self.wd.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='rf_version_details_info']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")
(Pdb) for i in elem: print i, i.text
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x036364D0>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x03636610>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x03636550>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x03636650> Aug. 8, 2014 at 17:01 (UTC)
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x03636630> Aug. 8, 2014 at 17:01 (UTC)
```